# How can a Discord.net bot send a message when it joins a guild in C#

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm working on a Discord.net bot, and I can't figure out how to make it send a message when it joins a new guild.

Here is what I have so far:

```
_client.JoinedGuild += AnnounceJoin;

public async Task AnnounceJoin(SocketGuildUser user)
{
    await user.Guild.SystemChannel.SendMessageAsync("I joined a server!");
    return;
}
```

But it gives the error `No overload for 'AnnounceJoin' matches delegate 'Func<SocketGuild, Task>'`

How can I make this work?

Comment: Your signature for `AnnounceJoin` is `SocketGuildUser user`, but the event is expecting it to be `SocketGuild`

Comment: I know that, but I can't figure out how to send a message with ```SocketGuild```.